# Generating Random Pairs of Integers without Replacement in R

Tags: r, random

I want to draw random integer pairs without replacement (said another way I don't want any duplicate pairs).  This concept sounds simple but I can't think of a quick and simple solution.

Imagine, for example, I want to generate random pairs of integers using the sequence of integer `1:4` to populate the elements of the pair.  Also assume I want to generate 5 random pairs without replacement.  I then want to be able to generate something like this...

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    3
[4,]    1    4
[5,]    4    3
```

In the above example, there are no duplicate pairs (i.e rows).  There are, however, duplicate integers within each column of the above matrix.  Consequently, using `sample()` to generate random number for each column separately will not work.

Another seemingly potential solution which will not work for my context is to generate numerous pairs which include duplicates and then delete these duplicates retroactively.  I can't do this because I will need to generate a specific number of pairs.

I'm looking for an efficient solution to this problem.  This seems like such a simple question, it must have a simple solution (i.e. please no nested for loops)

Here is my ugly approach:

```
#This matrix maps a unique id i.e. (1:16) to a pair (i.e. the row & col of the matrix)
r.mat<-matrix(1:(4*4),4,4) 
#Drawing a random id
r.id<-sample(r.mat,5,replace=FALSE)
#Mapping the random id to a random pair
r.pair<-t(sapply(r.id, function (x) which(r.mat==x,arr.ind=TRUE)))
```

This will work fine for my toy example but when I want to draw a large amount of pairs from the sequence 1:10000000, it is not so great.

Comment: how do you get {3,3} *without* replacement

Comment: Exactly how large is the sequence you're contemplating to draw each number from?  Is it really 1e7?

Comment: rawr - the set i'm essentially drawing from is (1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2), etc...  So without replacement means essentially that I will never have a duplicate pair.  Does that make sense?  Any advice on how to reword the question so it is more clear?

Comment: BrodieG, I'm at the beginning of a project so I'm not sure how big the sequence will be,  probably not 1e7.  But much closer to 1e7 than 4.

Comment: @DavidRobinson where did your answer go?

Comment: DavidRobinson's answer was wrong

Comment: You can improve the performance of the last line computing `r.pair` by computing the row and column directly, a constant-time operation, replacing the linear-time operation `which`: the row is `as.integer((x-1)%%4)+1L` and the column is `as.integer((x-1)/4)+1L`, where `x` is as in the function in the `sapply` call.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I hadn't actually seen your comment when I wrote my answer, but I ended up partly using this logic.

Comment: @BrodieG No worries.  It's a common idiom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key here is not to generate all the permutations as that is very expensive memory and time wise.  Since you only care about two numbers, we can do this very easily so long as the `(number_of_possible_values) ^ 2` is less than the largest representable integer in double precision floating point:

```
size <- 1e5
samples <- 100
vals <- sample.int(size ^ 2, samples)
cbind(vals %/% size + 1, vals %% size)
```

Basically, we use integers to represent every possible combination of values.  In our example, we sample from all the numbers up to `1e5 ^ 2`, since we have `1e5 ^ 2` possible combinations of `1e5` numbers.  Each of those `1e10` integers represents one of the combinations.  We then decompose that integer into the two component values by taking the modulo, as the first number, and the integer division as the second.

Benchmarks:

```
Unit: microseconds
                   expr        min         lq       mean
  funBrodie(10000, 100)     16.457     17.188     22.052
 funRichard(10000, 100) 542513.717 640647.919 638045.215
```

Also, limit should be ~3x1e7, and remains relatively fast:

```
Unit: microseconds
                  expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval
 funBrodie(1e+07, 100) 18.285 20.6625 22.88209 21.211 22.4905 77.893   100
```

Functions for benchmarking:

```
funRichard <- function(size, samples) {
  nums <- 1:size
  dt = CJ(nums, nums)
  dt[sample(1:dim(dt)[1], size = samples), ]
}
funBrodie <- function(size, samples) {
  vals <- sample.int(size ^ 2, samples)
  cbind(vals %/% size + 1, vals %% size)
}
```

And confirm we're doing similar things (note it's not a given these should be exactly the same, but it turns out they are):

```
set.seed(1)
resB <- funBrodie(1e4, 100)
set.seed(1)
resR <- unname(as.matrix(funRichard(1e4, 100)))
all.equal(resB, resR)
# TRUE
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the `CJ` method to you bench mark test. I'm curious how it compares to the other methods.

Comment: @RichardErickson, see updated (removing the `data.table`, which oddly actually added a fair bit of overhead).  Note previous answer was already using `CJ`, just unnecessarily wrapping it in a `data.table` call (I guess it make sense, that would copy a largish data set).

Comment: Thanks!  This is a better approach.

Comment: @JacobH, you're welcome.  Also, please note I just realized this can be done completely vectorized <headdesk> for another 10-15x speedup (see update to get rid of `sapply`).

Comment: Suppose `size` is 3 and `samples` is 1. Then, `vals` could be 9, and so you would assign `4, 0`, and neither 4 nor 0 lie in the range 1:3. Should it not be `((vals-1) %/% size) + 1` and `(vals %% size) + 1` in order to answer the original question?

Answer (score 4):

First, I found how to generate the pairs on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710340/generating-non-duplicate-permutation-pairs-in-r). However, that didn't scale so I looked in up `?combn` and found the `expand.grid` function.

Next, I use the `data.table` package because it handles large data well (see it's documentation for the why).

```
## the data.table library does well with large data sets
library(data.table)

## Small dummy dataset
pairOne = 1:10
pairTwo = 1:2
nSamples = 3

system.time({
dt = data.table(expand.grid(pairOne, pairTwo))
dt2 = dt[sample(1:dim(dt)[1], size = nSamples), ]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.002   0.001   0.001 

## Large dummy dataset
pairOne = 1:10000
pairTwo = 1:10000
length(pairOne) * length(pairTwo)
nSamples = 1e5
system.time({
dt = data.table(expand.grid(pairOne, pairTwo))
dt2 = dt[sample(1:dim(dt)[1], size = nSamples), ]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.576   1.276   3.862
```

Comment: The linked questions at your linked answer contain a number of interesting approaches and variations.  Clearly a challenging question, and you've done well!

Comment: Thanks!  This is great.  That expand.grid function is very convenient.

Comment: use `CJ()` instead of `expand.grid()`.

Comment: @Arun, what package is `CJ()` in? `?CJ` didn't find anything and a Goolge search for "CJ" R didn't yield any useful hits.

Comment: For future reference, the here's the `CJ` method `dt = CJ(pairOne, pairTwo); 
system.time({
dt = CJ(pairOne, pairTwo)
dt2 = dt[sample(1:dim(dt)[1], size = nSamples), ]
})`. This method 0.42 seconds total. And wow, `data.table` never stops amazing me! @Arun

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by David Robinson's initial stab:

```
set.seed(1)
np <- 1000 # number of elements desired
M1 <- t(combn(1:np, 2))
sam <- sample(1:nrow(M1), np, replace = FALSE)
M2 <- M1[sam,]
anyDuplicated(M2) # returns FALSE
```

This would use all possible entries of `M1` but in a random order.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I tried your solution as I was writing mine up. However, `combn` gives an error with large numbers (e.g., 1e7): `test = combn(1e7,2)` gives this error: 
`Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(1e+07, 2) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Bummer.  Plus `combn` is quite slow even for 10,000 points. So much for lean code!

Comment: Yeah, `R` can suck at scaling up...looking through the code, `expand.grid` appears to be faster than `combn`. `exapnd.grid` is using `data.frames` while `combn` is using matrices.  I wonder if that is why it is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. It doesn't look very elegant, but it's still a bit faster than @Richard Erickson's (2.0s vs 2.6s, for the same sizes). The idea is avoid creating the permutations, because that can take a lot of time and use a lot of memory. Instead, I create two random samples of IDs in the given range, and check if any row happens to be duplicated (which is very unlikely for a high range and average samples). If they are duplicated, then a new sample for column 2 is created and everything repeated.

```
range <- 1e8
n <- 1e5
ids1 <- sample(range, n)
ids2 <- sample(range, n)
mat1 <- cbind(ids1, ids2)
found = FALSE
while(!found) {
  if (any(duplicated(rbind(mat1, mat1[,2:1])))) {
    ids2 <- sample(range, n)
    mat1 <- cbind(ids1, ids2)
  } else {
    found=TRUE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
no.pairs.needed <- 4 # or however many you want
npairs<-0
pairs <- NULL
top.sample.range <- 10000  # or whatever

while (npairs < no.pairs.needed){
  newpair <- matrix(data=sample(1:top.sample.range,2), nrow=1, ncol=2)
 if(!anyDuplicated(rbind(pairs, newpair))){
    pairs <- rbind(pairs, newpair)
    npairs <- npairs+1
  }
}
```

Then object `pairs` will return the matrix you need. Seems to scale ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

```
allIDX <- seq(10000000)
prtIDX <- sample(1:10000000, 10000000/2)
chlIDX <- allIDX[-prtIDX]
pairIDX <- cbind(prtIDX,chlIDX)
```

But I didn't have to deal with 10000000.