# Generating unique row pairs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I'm trying to do something really simple but can't get it done.

I've got this data frame:

```
structure(list(First_ID = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
9L, 20L), First_Lat = c(14.60543375, 14.60928364, 14.60928364, 
14.55621093, 14.50756, 14.5802, 14.5802, 14.66019), First_Lon = c(-90.53911871, 
-90.53998477, -90.53998477, -90.54753174, -90.47934, -90.54794, 
-90.54794, -90.49326), First_11.Territrorios = c("Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

And I want to create another one with all possible matches to get it looking like this:

```
structure(list(X.U.FEFF.First_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L), First_Lat = c(14.60543375, 14.60543375, 
14.60543375, 14.60543375, 14.60543375, 14.60543375, 14.60543375, 
14.60928364, 14.60928364, 14.60928364, 14.60928364, 14.60928364, 
14.60928364, 14.60928364, 14.60928364, 14.60928364, 14.60928364, 
14.60928364, 14.55621093, 14.55621093, 14.55621093, 14.55621093, 
14.50756, 14.50756, 14.50756, 14.5802, 14.5802, 14.5802), First_Lon = c(-90.53911871, 
-90.53911871, -90.53911871, -90.53911871, -90.53911871, -90.53911871, 
-90.53911871, -90.53998477, -90.53998477, -90.53998477, -90.53998477, 
-90.53998477, -90.53998477, -90.53998477, -90.53998477, -90.53998477, 
-90.53998477, -90.53998477, -90.54753174, -90.54753174, -90.54753174, 
-90.54753174, -90.47934, -90.47934, -90.47934, -90.54794, -90.54794, 
-90.54794), First_11.Territrorios = c("Guate", "Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate"), Second_ID = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 9L, 20L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 20L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 20L, 
6L, 8L, 9L, 20L, 8L, 9L, 20L, 9L, 20L, 20L), Second_Lat = c(14.60928364, 
14.60928364, 14.55621093, 14.50756, 14.5802, 14.5802, 14.66019, 
14.60928364, 14.55621093, 14.50756, 14.5802, 14.5802, 14.66019, 
14.55621093, 14.50756, 14.5802, 14.5802, 14.66019, 14.50756, 
14.5802, 14.5802, 14.66019, 14.5802, 14.5802, 14.66019, 14.5802, 
14.66019, 14.66019), Second_Lon = c(-90.53998477, -90.53998477, 
-90.54753174, -90.47934, -90.54794, -90.54794, -90.49326, -90.53998477, 
-90.54753174, -90.47934, -90.54794, -90.54794, -90.49326, -90.54753174, 
-90.47934, -90.54794, -90.54794, -90.49326, -90.47934, -90.54794, 
-90.54794, -90.49326, -90.54794, -90.54794, -90.49326, -90.54794, 
-90.49326, -90.49326), Second_11.Territrorios = c("Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", 
"Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate", "Guate")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

By repeiting each row with each other until there's no more pairs left! - I've tried using [combn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710340/generating-non-duplicate-combination-pairs-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) function but it gives me a list creating all pairs for each column as a new object and I only want a single data frame doing it for all. Also tried using [expand.grid](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-July/282834.html) but it's giving me this error:

```
Error in paste0(nmc[i], "=", if (is.numeric(x)) format(x) else x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Weird. I have no problem with `expand.grid`. Have you tried this in a fresh R session? My first guess is that you have a function name that matches something in your data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method:

```r
combinations <- combn(8,2)
combinations
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4     5     5     5     6     6     7
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    3    4     5     6     7     8     4     5     6     7     8     5     6     7     8     6     7     8     7     8     8
out <- cbind(dat[combinations[1,],], dat[combinations[2,],])

names(out) <- c(names(dat), gsub("First", "Second", names(dat)))
out
#     First_ID First_Lat First_Lon First_11.Territrorios Second_ID Second_Lat Second_Lon Second_11.Territrorios
# 1          1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         2   14.60928  -90.53998                  Guate
# 1.1        1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         4   14.60928  -90.53998                  Guate
# 1.2        1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         5   14.55621  -90.54753                  Guate
# 1.3        1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         6   14.50756  -90.47934                  Guate
# 1.4        1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         8   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 1.5        1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         9   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 1.6        1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate        20   14.66019  -90.49326                  Guate
# 2          2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         4   14.60928  -90.53998                  Guate
# 2.1        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         5   14.55621  -90.54753                  Guate
# 2.2        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         6   14.50756  -90.47934                  Guate
# 2.3        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         8   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 2.4        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         9   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 2.5        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate        20   14.66019  -90.49326                  Guate
# 3          4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         5   14.55621  -90.54753                  Guate
# 3.1        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         6   14.50756  -90.47934                  Guate
# 3.2        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         8   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 3.3        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         9   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 3.4        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate        20   14.66019  -90.49326                  Guate
# 4          5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate         6   14.50756  -90.47934                  Guate
# 4.1        5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate         8   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 4.2        5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate         9   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 4.3        5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate        20   14.66019  -90.49326                  Guate
# 5          6  14.50756 -90.47934                 Guate         8   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 5.1        6  14.50756 -90.47934                 Guate         9   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 5.2        6  14.50756 -90.47934                 Guate        20   14.66019  -90.49326                  Guate
# 6          8  14.58020 -90.54794                 Guate         9   14.58020  -90.54794                  Guate
# 6.1        8  14.58020 -90.54794                 Guate        20   14.66019  -90.49326                  Guate
# 7          9  14.58020 -90.54794                 Guate        20   14.66019  -90.49326                  Guate
```

Another method, though less efficient because it does a full cartesian join before filtering:

```r
subset(merge(dat, dat, by = NULL), First_ID.x < First_ID.y)
#    First_ID.x First_Lat.x First_Lon.x First_11.Territrorios.x First_ID.y First_Lat.y First_Lon.y First_11.Territrorios.y
# 9           1    14.60543   -90.53912                   Guate          2    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate
# 17          1    14.60543   -90.53912                   Guate          4    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate
# 18          2    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          4    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate
# 25          1    14.60543   -90.53912                   Guate          5    14.55621   -90.54753                   Guate
# 26          2    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          5    14.55621   -90.54753                   Guate
# 27          4    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          5    14.55621   -90.54753                   Guate
# 33          1    14.60543   -90.53912                   Guate          6    14.50756   -90.47934                   Guate
# 34          2    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          6    14.50756   -90.47934                   Guate
# 35          4    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          6    14.50756   -90.47934                   Guate
# 36          5    14.55621   -90.54753                   Guate          6    14.50756   -90.47934                   Guate
# 41          1    14.60543   -90.53912                   Guate          8    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 42          2    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          8    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 43          4    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          8    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 44          5    14.55621   -90.54753                   Guate          8    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 45          6    14.50756   -90.47934                   Guate          8    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 49          1    14.60543   -90.53912                   Guate          9    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 50          2    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          9    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 51          4    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate          9    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 52          5    14.55621   -90.54753                   Guate          9    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 53          6    14.50756   -90.47934                   Guate          9    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 54          8    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate          9    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate
# 57          1    14.60543   -90.53912                   Guate         20    14.66019   -90.49326                   Guate
# 58          2    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate         20    14.66019   -90.49326                   Guate
# 59          4    14.60928   -90.53998                   Guate         20    14.66019   -90.49326                   Guate
# 60          5    14.55621   -90.54753                   Guate         20    14.66019   -90.49326                   Guate
# 61          6    14.50756   -90.47934                   Guate         20    14.66019   -90.49326                   Guate
# 62          8    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate         20    14.66019   -90.49326                   Guate
# 63          9    14.58020   -90.54794                   Guate         20    14.66019   -90.49326                   Guate
```

Row names are distracting but harmless. Column names can be updated as in the first example.

The biggest difference between doing the `cbind` *outside* `combn` (as above) versus *inside* using `FUN=` is that doing it outside makes one call to `cbind`; inside it makes in this example 28 calls to `cbind` then combines the results. While performance is not a concern with this dataset, it is certainly less efficient to iterate over each combination.

Answer (score 1):

Try `combn` like below

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  combn(nrow(df),
    2,
    function(x) {
      cbind(
        df[x[1], ],
        setNames(df[x[2], ], gsub("First", "Second", names(df)))
      )
    },
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   First_ID First_Lat First_Lon First_11.Territrorios Second_ID Second_Lat
1         1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         2   14.60928
2         1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         4   14.60928
3         1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         5   14.55621
4         1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         6   14.50756
5         1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         8   14.58020
6         1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate         9   14.58020
7         1  14.60543 -90.53912                 Guate        20   14.66019
21        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         4   14.60928
22        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         5   14.55621
23        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         6   14.50756
24        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         8   14.58020
25        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         9   14.58020
26        2  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate        20   14.66019
31        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         5   14.55621
32        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         6   14.50756
33        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         8   14.58020
34        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate         9   14.58020
35        4  14.60928 -90.53998                 Guate        20   14.66019
41        5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate         6   14.50756
42        5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate         8   14.58020
43        5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate         9   14.58020
44        5  14.55621 -90.54753                 Guate        20   14.66019
51        6  14.50756 -90.47934                 Guate         8   14.58020
52        6  14.50756 -90.47934                 Guate         9   14.58020
53        6  14.50756 -90.47934                 Guate        20   14.66019
61        8  14.58020 -90.54794                 Guate         9   14.58020
62        8  14.58020 -90.54794                 Guate        20   14.66019
71        9  14.58020 -90.54794                 Guate        20   14.66019
   Second_Lon Second_11.Territrorios
1   -90.53998                  Guate
2   -90.53998                  Guate
3   -90.54753                  Guate
4   -90.47934                  Guate
5   -90.54794                  Guate
6   -90.54794                  Guate
7   -90.49326                  Guate
21  -90.53998                  Guate
22  -90.54753                  Guate
23  -90.47934                  Guate
24  -90.54794                  Guate
25  -90.54794                  Guate
26  -90.49326                  Guate
31  -90.54753                  Guate
32  -90.47934                  Guate
33  -90.54794                  Guate
34  -90.54794                  Guate
35  -90.49326                  Guate
41  -90.47934                  Guate
42  -90.54794                  Guate
43  -90.54794                  Guate
44  -90.49326                  Guate
51  -90.54794                  Guate
52  -90.54794                  Guate
53  -90.49326                  Guate
61  -90.54794                  Guate
62  -90.49326                  Guate
71  -90.49326                  Guate
```

Comment: Interesting ... not only is this effectively the same as mine (albeit moving code from outside to inside `combn`, and slower/less-efficient), but it was provided well after my answer. It's good technique, @ThomasIsCoding (and I'm not blaming you), but it seems odd to me.

Comment: @r2evans yes, I see that yours is more efficient and the upvote is from me.

Comment: @r2evans no worries. I just realized that yours is better after seeing your answer so I gave an upvote to you. Anyway, the acceptance is up to OP's choice, no one knows the reason behind.